# Where is the login for connection to base?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I to do connection and have error.

```
from u in db.aspnet_users where u.UserName.Equals(email) select u
```

error:

> Cannot open database "AdvSkidki" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'USER\User'.

I can not understand where the data user / user.

I have only `<add name="AdvSkidkiEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Model.csdl|res://*/Entities.Model.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=AdvSkidki;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />` in web.config in myproject.

query to the database is in myproject.Domain.Conrete

**update:**

if the *. edmx located in the main project - all works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nonnb pointed the problem, you have 3 solutions :

- **Change WebSite (app pool) identity** as already said : you must have access to the IIS server (only IIS 6.0 and greater have Application Pools). There's a lot of articles and Microsoft docs about it, check this [one for IIS 6](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511/IIS-and-ASPNET-The-Application-Pool.htm), and this [one for IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)
- **Specificy a username and password** in the [connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) instead of `Integrated
  security`
- **Impersonate the application/code section** and continue with `Integrated
  security`, see [how to impersonate a web application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [how to impersonate a code section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w070t6ka.aspx)

Comment: I create new project (asp.net mvc3) and it worked, the last class library project

Answer (score 2):

Because you have indicated `integrated security=True;` in your connection string, it means that the Application Pool running your app needs to be granted access to your database.

Either add `USER\User` as a [login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) to the SQLExpress server, with sufficient access to the `AdvSkidki` database, or change the [identity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) of your App Pool to one that does have access to the database.

Comment: How "change the identity of your App Pool to one that does have access to the database." do this?